# created new visual studio 2010 test project after build says could not load its own file or assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have been working with creating a brand new test projects in VS 2010 tonight. Immediately after creating the project which VS 2010 supplies with a test file to show me how to work with it's attributes, I build and get the following:

> Error loading ...my documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestProject1\bin\Debug\TestProject1.dll: Could not load
>   file or assembly ...\my documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestProject1\bin\Debug\TestProject1.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131515)

I don't have any dependencies or references. Why can't I build a test project in VS immediately after creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a network permissions issue on where your project files were being saved.
Just saving stuff locally will fix your problem. Maybe!

Or you can try [**Unblocking Any Protected Files**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80131515.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm, so you must have one of those crystal balls I keep hearing about that is like Remote Desktop but not. For grins and giggles I got on my vpn and now when I build I do not get any build errors. You were right, the fully qualified file name which I chopped part of it off for privacy issues was looking for a network location on the vpn. I really dislike how this laptop and the vpn behave with software development. Thanks Tonix!

Comment: FWIW, while on the vpn, I found out the error was not a build issue, it was a "Test" issue/error message. In output window the dropdown says "Test" when it displays this error.